# Can't return image from WCF Rest service

Tags: c#, wcf, image, rest

As topic says, I having a problem to receive an image from my Wcf rest service.  The endpoint seems to be alright but i only get empty data back.

Web.config:

```
  <service name="RestService.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address ="" binding="webHttpBinding"                     contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
```

SVC:

```
        [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetImage", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    Stream GetImage();

    public Stream GetImage()
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        Resource1.batman.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "image/png";
        return ms;
    }
```

Markup:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="RestService.RestServiceImpl" CodeBehind="RestServiceImpl.svc.cs" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory"%>
```

Comment: Try setting the Position of the memory stream back to 0 before returning. Are you using this call from a browser?
Why not return the String location of the image and let the browser load it?

Comment: Thanks Erix! Setting ms.Position = 0; before return did the trick!

Comment: You're welcome. I've added that as an answer if you wouldn't mind marking it. (It was an answer before but a mod deleted it for some stupid reason)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the Position of the memory stream back to 0 before returning.